# Sort a QAbstractListModel derived model by role in QML ListView

Tags: qt, sorting, qml, qabstractlistmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've created a QAbstractListModel derived model based on an underlying QHash. Since I need to use the model in QML, I cannot make use of the sorting functionality Qt widgets and views have integrated.

I tried using a QSortFilterProxyModel but it doesn't seem to work with my model. Getting the model to properly work in QML wasn't tedious enough, and now I am stuck on sorting.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is the model source:

```
typedef QHash<QString, uint> Data;

class NewModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int count READ count NOTIFY countChanged)

public:
    NewModel(QObject * parent = 0) : QAbstractListModel(parent) {}

    enum Roles {WordRole = Qt::UserRole, CountRole};

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[WordRole] = "word";
        roles[CountRole] = "count";
        return roles;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_data.size()) return QVariant();
        Data::const_iterator iter = m_data.constBegin() + index.row();

        switch (role) {
        case WordRole:
            return iter.key();
        case CountRole:
            return iter.value();
        } return QVariant();
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        return m_data.size();
    }

    int count() const { return m_data.size(); }

public slots:
    void append(const QString &word) {
        bool alreadyThere = m_data.contains(word);
        if (alreadyThere) m_data[word]++;
        else m_data.insert(word, 1);

        Data::const_iterator iter = m_data.find(word);
        uint position = delta(iter);

        if (alreadyThere) {
            QModelIndex index = createIndex(position, 0);
            emit dataChanged(index, index);
        } else {
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position);
            endInsertRows();
            emit countChanged();
        }
    }

    void prepend(const QString &word) {
        if (m_data.contains(word)) m_data[word]++;
        else m_data.insert(word, 1);
    }

signals:
    void countChanged();

private:
    uint delta(Data::const_iterator i) {
        uint d = 0;
        while (i != m_data.constBegin()) { ++d; --i; }
        return d;
    }

    Data m_data;
};
```

Here is "trying" to sort it:

```
NewModel model;
QAbstractItemModel * pm = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemModel *>(&model);
QSortFilterProxyModel proxy;
proxy.setSourceModel(pm);
proxy.setSortRole(NewModel::WordRole);
proxy.setDynamicSortFilter(true);
```

Alas, the proxy works as a model, but it doesn't sort the entries.

Answer (score 8):

If you enable QSortFilterProxyModel::setDynamicSortFilter(true), you need to call QSortFilterProxyModel::sort(...) function once to let the proxy know which way to sort.

With that, any time the model is updated the proxy will sort everything again just automatically.

```
proxy.setDynamicSortFilter(true);
proxy.sort(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, There's no need for `qobject_cast<QAbstractItemModel *>` downcasting -- the `NewModel` is a derived class of the `QAbstractItemModel` and the polymorphism principle says that you can use a subclass everywhere where a parent class is applicable.

Second, your `prepend` method does not use `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`. That's a violation of the MVC API. You'll get data corruption in the attached views and proxy models if you use it this way.

Third, you haven't mentioned whether you're actually using your proxy model as the model for the attached view :).

Finally, you are using `QHash` as a backing store of your data with `QHash::iterator` for insertion. That's an itneresting solution, but something which just cannot work -- an insertion or removal can cause the hash table to grow/shrink, which means changing all data you publish via your model indexes. This is just not going to work. Don't use `QHash` when you need a stable order. The `O(n)` complexity of your `delta` method should be interpreted as a warning; this is a wrong approach.

Comment: `prepend()` is used to populate the model when it is not used, there is no problem with using it wisely. I need to use QHash for the lookup, I've already done this by using the hash for storage and then transferring the data to another model, but I am looking for ways to reuse the original data from the hash. The model as it is appears to work OK, my issue is only with sorting.

Comment: Try to run the ModelTest on top of your code, you might be rather surprised.

Comment: It is used in a tightly specified context, the thought that it is perfect as a part of the entire API is far removed, I only aim for functionality I need in particular. Maybe that is why it doesn't work with the sorting proxy. It will be easier to do my own sorting proxy wrapper than to make the stock one work with the model while keeping the underlying container optimized for fastest lookup, which is the N1 requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel. This project exposes the functionality of QSortFilterProxyModel nicely to QML. I used it in different projects and it junst worked. However if you want to implement your own solution it's something to get your ideas.